# Format display of timedelta() Python Django

Tags: python, django, templates, format, timedelta

I have an object which has "time" property.

"time" property value is seconds.

I'm using tempalate filter to change it into desired format:

```
@register.filter(name="timedelta")
def timedelta(timedeltaobj):
    delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=timedeltaobj)
    return delta
```

This filter returns correct value, for example:

```
1:01:07.249000
```

But the problem is that i want only 3 digits after comma "1:01:07.249".
Is there any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert result to string and trim last three symbols:

```
@register.filter(name="timedelta")
def timedelta(timedeltaobj):
    delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=timedeltaobj)
    return str(delta)[:-3]
```